# AngularFire2: Getting empty object from database

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular2-services, angularfire2

I'm following the [AngularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md) doc for setting up Firebase for my project. I'm unable to retrieve any data from database.

```
  contacts:Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(angularFire: AngularFirestore, public http: Http) { 
    this.contacts = angularFire.collection('mycontacts').valueChanges()   
    console.log("Contacts : "+ this.contacts)
  }
```

My Firebase JSON structure below:

```
"mycontacts" : {
"Contacts" : {
  "John" : {
    "Address" : "3 London Road",
    "Email" : "john@hotmail.com",
    "FirstName" : "John",
    "LastName" : "Snow",
    "PhoneNo" : "074236482878"
  }}}
```

**Result**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you have rightly defined, the `contacts` property in your component is an `Observable`. Hence simply `console.log`ging it won't give you the data you are looking for. If if you wanna extract the data inside the component, then you have to subscribe to it using `subscribe`

```
angularFire.collection('mycontacts').valueChanges().subscribe((data) => {
 this.contacts = data;
});
```

Having said that, if all you want is to just show the data instead on your page (template), then you could simply use the `async` pipe to show the Observable data asynchronously on your page.

```
this.contacts = angularFire.collection('mycontacts').valueChanges(); // same code you had
```

in your template, use the pipe, for example

```
<div *ngFor="let contact of contacts | async" [innerHTML]="contact"></div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Amal, i'm getting the following error "The Cloud Firestore API is not enabled for the project"